# Gnome extensions and Ubuntu versions

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I updated to 19.04 from 18.10 in April/May but some of my Gnome extensions failed to appear in the task-bar and so I reverted back to a Clonezilla copy of my 18.10 installtion. I now have more time to play around with 19.04 and so intend to try again. I have one question before I take the plunge.

I have backed up my Gnome Extensions with:

```
/usr/bin/dconf dump /org/gnome/ > /media/steve/6363-6333/Gnome-Backups/gnome-backup
cp -r ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions  /media/steve/6363-6333/Gnome-Backups/extensions-bkup
```

And thought if I have problems I could do:

```
dconf load /org/gnome/ < /media/steve/6363-6333/Gnome-Backups/gnome-backup
cp -r /media/steve/6363-6333/Gnome-Backups/extensions-bkup ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Would this work between Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some GNOME extensions won't work in 19.04. `Dash to Dock` is one popular extension that some folks have trouble with, but there are others, some with serious issues.

The SAFEST way to upgrade to 19.04 is to temporarily DISABLE ALL GNOME extensions in 18.10 at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/.

Then upgrade to 19.04, get it running, and THEN re-enable one GNOME extension at a time at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. You can immediately tell if an extension has a problem as a RED error icon will appear next to its name. If the newly enabled extension doesn't function as it should, it's not compatible. Another way to tell if you've got an incompatible extension is to watch `/var/log/syslog` for errors from `gnome-shell`.

```
grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*
```